# Wired Mouse cursor freezes for a few seconds if lifted off the surface

Tags: usb, drivers, windows-11, razer-mouse, razer-synapse

In the last week Razer Basilisk V3 (USB cable mouse) cursor freezes if mouse if lifted for a second. Whenever I lift the mouse to adjust placement of mouse on mat, the cursor becomes unresponsive (including all buttons on mouse) for a 1-2 seconds before responding again. Moreover if I keep the mouse lifted off the surface for more than 5-6 seconds, the device is not recognized by Razer Synapse or the Windows itself; I have to unplug the mouse and re-plug it to get it back working again. Tried other mice in my system, works fine. Tried my Razer mouse on other system, works fine.
I'm using a Lenovo Legion 5 Pro Ryzen 7 5800H with RTX 3070. Both Laptop and Mouse bought in 2021

Solutions tried:

- Wipe razer software (all of them), uninstall all the razer drivers and full clean reinstallation.
- Upgraded from Win 10 to Win 11, hoping it would solve some driver issues, didn't work
- Calibrated Lift-off Distance from Razer Synapse, not an issue, works fine for a few mm distance, but as I go beyond that vertical distance mouse becomes unresponsive
- Disabled power saving (management) for all USB ports, Razer devices from Device Manager
- Checked/repaired registry errors, didn't fix the problem
- Contacted Razer support, they don't have a clue
- Uninstall Riot Vanguard, Valorant (saw on reddit it was causing problem for some razer mice)
- Uninstalled any software installed in last month
- Checked for malware, virus
- Troubleshooting from windows, reinstalling laptop OEM drivers, windows update, Lenovo vantage driver update. All the updates I could possibly think of, I have already done

Please let me know if anyone can help me with this. Let me re-iterate, mouse works fine on other system, and other mice work fine on my current system. Only the combination of this Laptop and and Mouse is not working for last week.

Comment: Ive had a similar problem with a Roccat mouse. When lifted a bit too high of the mouse mat, the cursor would freeze for 1 or 2 seconds and then resume as if nothing had happened. Never found a fix for it though.

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if this was a "feature" in the razer software, sort of how laptops have a "disable touchpad while typing" feature...